# How to read special characters with RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve SEO compliant clean urls.
The control panel i'm using for my website already allows to simply activate clean-urls within its core settings. This simply changes all the internal links accordingly, nothing else.
So what i'm trying to do here now is to set the proper RewriteRule settings within the .htaccess file

This is what i was able to come up with:

.htaccess specific settings look as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ?module=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ ?module=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/\?id=(\w+)$ ?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Real address that works:

`https://example.com/?module=character&action=view&id=500001`

With activated Clean URL it becomes:

`https://example.com/character/view/?id=500001`

With the current .htaccess settings as shown above 
`https://example.com/character/view/` works just fine
while everything that comes after does not work. (?id=500001)

I've tried to read the ?id= properly with the last RewriteRule but did not manage to get it to work. I may be missunderstanding how i'm able to write special characters within the RewriteRule, the question mark in this particular case.

Been reading through several guides and info pages but didn't quite wrap my head around it because i never found something about special characters.

Typing it directly or within brackets also did not seem to bring the required result.

Hoping for some enlightenment on this most likely noobish question.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the first ? in a URL is considered the GET query string and as such not part of the string a RewriteRule pattern is matched against. You can use a RewriteCond for that, but it is questionable anyway, since such URL you use is not clean in the sense most people call "SEO friendly".

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ /?module=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /?module=$1&action=$2 [END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /?module=$1&action=$2&id=%1 [END]
```

Instead your URL should read https://example.com/character/view/500001 which simplifies things:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ ?module=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ ?module=$1&action=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)$ ?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

Those rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

Oh, and by the way:

There is no such thing as "special characters", stop acting as if there are good and bad characters. There are only characters. Today's standard is Unicode or at least UTF-8. That encoding defines roughly 108000 characters, all of them are equally valid and normal, none is "special". ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the indept information.
However setting it to your suggested SEO improved version wasn't my goal.

This control panels sets all links as stated above to:
/?id=500001
And not just that, it's a very complex control panel which consists of tons of similiar content pages. And i don't want to interfere with the core of the control panel to get it outputting the clean urls differently.

So i'm trying to solve that:

https://example.com/character/view/?id=500001

Actualy becomes 

https://example.com/?module=character&action=view&id=500001

Comment: I can't really follow... You explained that things don't work. So I tried to explain _why_ they don't work, how you can get them to work. The first solution does what you ask in your comment here... In addition I pointed out what might be a better approach - better in the sense of cleaner and easier. I fail to see why you don't want that, but that is not my decision ;-) All fine, good luck!

Comment: I repeat:
Your better solution is not possible for me, because the system is use forces the above stated *clean* urls.